# Angular2 framework get JWT token

Tags: angular, jwt

I have a SpringBoot backend Java application that returns a JWT. here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String login(@RequestBody Customer login) throws ServletException {

            String jwtToken = "";

            if (login.getUsername()== null || login.getPassword()== null) {
                throw new ServletException("Please fill in username and password");
            }

            String username = login.getUsername();
            String password = login.getPassword();

            Customer customer = customerservice.findByusername(username);

            if (customer == null) {
                throw new ServletException("Username not found.");
            }

            String pwd = customer.getPassword();

            if (!password.equals(pwd)) {
                throw new ServletException("Invalid login. Please check your name and password.");
            }

            jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).claim("roles", "administrator").setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "ZGVkeXB1amk=").compact();

            return jwtToken;
        }
```

it return TEXT like this

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkZWR5cHVqaSIsInJvbGVzIjoiYWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciIsImlhdCI6MTQ5NzA3NDQ3OX0.i7CjOhNScJRZc5dKhGaNFwje_5-PcOWDwlHD68fmOrw

how in my angular2 code to save that token and get the username

here is my angular2 code so far

the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import {CustomerData} from '../model/customer';
import {Auth} from '../model/auth';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerCustomer( registerdata:CustomerData){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/customer/new", JSON.stringify(registerdata), {headers: this.headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

  login(auth:Auth){

    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/admin/login", JSON.stringify(auth), {headers: this.headers})
    .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                if (token) {
                    // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: auth.username, token: token }));

                    // return true to indicate successful login
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return false;
                }
            }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

  }


  }
```

the class model Auth

```
export class Auth {
    public username:string;
    public password:string;
}
```

and the component of login

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {CustomerService} from '../services/customer.service';
import {Auth} from '../model/auth';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-login-admin',
  templateUrl: './app-login-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-login-admin.component.css'],
  providers:[CustomerService]

})
export class AppLoginAdminComponent implements OnInit {

  auth: Auth = new Auth();
  login_admin: FormGroup;
  private tmpresult: String = '';
  err: string;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private service: CustomerService,

    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.login_admin = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.service.login(this.login_admin.value)
  }

}
```

if I run the code. it returns nothing. IDK where is the fault? I check on the developer tool of google chrome and check the local storage but nothing token came up there. please help. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors.

1. You never actually send your POST request, because you never subscribe to the observable returned by the login() method.
2. Your service expects a JSON object containing a property `token`. But your spring controller doesn't return JSON. It returns a String.
3. You don't need to call JSON.stringify() and to pass a Content-Type header with the HTTP service. Just pass the object to send, and the service with stringify it for you, and set the appropriate content type.

Comment: the point number two you mention, is that error with my 'map((response: Response) => ' code ?

Comment: It's not an error. The code would be OK if the server did actually return a JSON object with a token property. And No, I won't write your code for you.

Comment: so i change the content type to text/plain and then i will use my map code still and then i have subscribe it, is that what you suggested, right?

Comment: What I suggest is 1. to subscribe, 2. to actually return a JSON object with a token property from your server, 3. to stop calling JSON.stringify and passing the Content-Type header.

Comment: i still didnt get the answer yet

Comment: The answer to what? Your question is "IDK where is the fault?" I answered it, didn't I?